# How to get a list of tasks triggered on idle?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, cmd.exe

Is there a way to get either via `cmd` or `powershell` the list of tasks that are triggered on idle?

---

#### Why do I need it?

I noticed a cpu consuming (25%) `svchost.exe` running when I don't do anything for a while. To confirm this I left the process explorer from sysinternals running and after several minutes the svchost appears. I don't know how to track it down because as soon as I move the mouse it disappears and stops so I'm not able to see more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I've found it:

```
Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object { $_.State -ne "Disabled" } | Select-Object TaskName, TaskPath, Triggers | Where-Object { $_.Triggers -match "MSFT_TaskIdleTrigger" }
```

Result:

> ```
> TaskName        Triggers                                      TaskPath
>   --------        --------                                      --------   
>   Installation    {MSFT_TaskLogonTrigger, MSFT_TaskIdleTrigger} \Microsoft\Windows\LanguageComponentsInstaller\ 
>   XblGameSaveTask {MSFT_TaskIdleTrigger}                        \Microsoft\XblGameSave\
> ```

Comment: I disabled both idle-triggers and now my notebook remains really idle ;-)

Comment: just a small little improvement: you don't need `select-object`, and you can make your two `where-object` into one: `Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object { $_.State -ne "Disabled" -and $_.Triggers -match "MSFT_TaskIdleTrigger"}`

Comment: Just FYI, there are other tasks that you may be interested that are not triggered on idle, but are triggered some other way with the *condition* that the PC is idle. An example is Microsoft/Windows/MemoryDiagnostic/RunFullMemoryDiagnostic . Even that isn't necessarily everything that can lead to "unnecessary" slowdown, as sometimes the idle determination/check is left to the program that is run. An example of this is Microsoft/Windows/Maintenance/WinSAT, which does a light benchmarking of your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  I was trying to list logon, startup, and high priority scheduled tasks.  (MSFT_TaskLogonTrigger, MSFT_TaskBootTrigger, $_.settings.priority -notmatch "7")